# Save/loading shapefiles with SF in R: no simple features geometry column present

Tags: shapefile, r, sf

I have this code:

```
library('sf')
#init data
xes = c(-122.133533701866, -122.141590665524, -122.382782560179, -122.302227764504, -122.347524548303)
yes = c(47.617342005802, 47.6102707417054, 47.6704037709971, 47.6118279934801, 47.7237286721321)
a = data.frame(id = 1:5, X = xes, Y = yes)

#init sf object
a = st_as_sf(a, coords = c('X','Y'))
st_crs(a) = 4326
st_write(a, "C:/Users/USER/Downloads/aa.shp", delete_dsn=TRUE)
test1 <- st_read("C:/Users/USER/Downloads/aa.shp", stringAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The final line (test1) returns:

> Error in st_sf(x, ..., agr = agr, sf_column_name = sf_column_name) : 
>     no simple features geometry column present

Which is odd, because using rgdal and converting to an sf object works just fine:

```
#Assumes code block above has already been run
library('rgdal')
a1= as(a, 'Spatial')

writeOGR(a1, 'C:/Users/USER/Downloads/aaa.shp', driver = 'ESRI Shapefile', layer = 'aaa', overwrite_layer = T)

#works
test2 = readOGR('C:/Users/USER/Downloads/aaa.shp')
test3 = readOGR('C:/Users/USER/Downloads/aa.shp') #from the earlier block
identical(test2,test3) #returns TRUE

b = st_as_sf(test2)

identical(a,b)
```

> [1] TRUE

SessionInfo:

> R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
>   LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United
>   States.1252 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C
>   LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1] rgdal_1.3-6       sp_1.3-1
>   data.table_1.11.8 openxlsx_4.1.0    sf_0.7-1
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] Rcpp_0.12.19
>   lattice_0.20-35 class_7.3-14    crayon_1.3.4    grid_3.5.1
>   spData_0.2.9.4  DBI_1.0.0       magrittr_1.5    e1071_1.7-0     [10]
>   units_0.6-1     pillar_1.3.0    zip_1.0.0       rlang_0.3.0.1
>   rstudioapi_0.8  tools_3.5.1     yaml_2.2.0      compiler_3.5.1 
>   classInt_0.2-3  [19] tibble_1.4.2

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a typo.

Comment: Had the same error. Google saved me. Got me here. The error message is a bit murky. (imho)

Comment: Had the same error too. My typo was CRS = ... instead of crs = ...! Rookie mistake, but I agree, the error could be more informative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`test1 <- st_read("C:/Users/USER/Downloads/aa.shp", stringAsFactors = FALSE)`

`stringAsFactors` is not `stringsAsFactors`. You've missed an `s`.